# Gson type token issue with generic deserialization

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have found many similar questions but none of them has helped.

This works:

```
public class Assets<T> {

public T getAndDeserializeAsset(String endpoint, String assetId, Client client){
    Response response = client.get(endpoint+assetId);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T asset = gson.fromJson(response.body, new TypeToken<Email>(){}.getType());
    return asset;
}
```

}

This doesn't:

```
public class Assets<T> {

public T getAndDeserializeAsset(String endpoint, String assetId, Client client){
    Response response = client.get(endpoint+assetId);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T asset = gson.fromJson(response.body, new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType());
    return asset;
}
```

}

I have made it according to official documentation, so I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rest.api.Response cannot be cast to model.Email
at main.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that makes sense is that your instance of `Assets<T>` must be an instance of `Assets<Response>`, not of `Assets<Email>`. Are you absolutely sure your instance of `Assets` is the correct type?

Also, remember that **Gson is not covariant**; when you specify the type using `TypeToken`, you must use the exact type you wish to deserialize to. For example, if you use the class definition:

```
class Email extends Response {
```

and then use:

```
new Assets<Response>();
```

Because Gson isn't covariant, has no way to know that what you really want is an `Email`.

Answer (score 0):

The above code fails to interpret value as type, because Gson invokes Assets.getClass() to get its class information, but this method returns a raw class, Assets.class. This means that Gson has no way of knowing that this is an object of type Assets< Example>, and not just plain Assets.

You can solve this problem by specifying the correct parameterized type for your generic type. You can do this by using the TypeToken class.

```
Type AssetsType = new TypeToken<Assets<Example>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(assets, AssetsType );
gson.fromJson(json, AssetsType );
```

for more information check [gson-user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)